# How to use TfidfVectorizer correctly?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, tf-idf

I always got error when using TfidfVectorizer for kmeans clustering.

There are 3 cases:

1. I use `tokenizer` parameter in TfidfVectorizer to customize tokenization process for my dataset. Here is my code:

   `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops,tokenizer=tokenize)
   X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)`

however i got this error :

```
ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words
```

2. I make a vocabulary consisting terms that was the result of the tokenization, so the code become like this:

   `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops,tokenizer=tokenize,vocabulary=vocab)`

but i got another new error:

```
ValueError: Vocabulary contains repeated indices.
```

3. And lastly, i remove the tokenizer and vocabulary parameter. The code becomes like this:

   `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stops)
   X = vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)
   terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
   true_k = 8
   model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
   model.fit(X)
   print "Top terms per cluster:"
   order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
   for i in range(true_k):
       print "Cluster %d:" % i,
       for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
           print ' %s' % terms[ind],
       print`

Well, the program runs successfully but the clustering results are like this:

`Cluster 0:  bangun,  rancang,  lunak,  perangkat,  aplikasi,  berbasis,  menggunakan,  service,  sistem,  pembangunan,
Cluster 1:  sistem,  aplikasi,  berbasis,  web,  menggunakan,  pembuatan,  mobile,  informasi,  teknologi,  pengembangan,
Cluster 2:  android,  berbasis,  aplikasi,  perangkat,  rancang,  bangun,  bergerak,  mobile,  sosial,  menggunakan,
Cluster 3:  implementasi,  algoritma,  menggunakan,  klasifikasi,  data,  game,  fuzzy,  vector,  support,  machine,
Cluster 4:  metode,  menggunakan,  video,  penerapan,  implementasi,  steganografi,  pengenalan,  berbasis,  file,  analisis,
Cluster 5:  citra,  segmentasi,  menggunakan,  implementasi,  metode,  warna,  tekstur,  kembali,  berwarna,  temu,
Cluster 6:  jaringan,  tiruan,  protokol,  voip,  syaraf,  saraf,  menggunakan,  implementasi,  kinerja,  streaming,
Cluster 7:  studi,  kasus,  its,  informatika,  teknik,  sistem,  informasi,  data,  surabaya,  jurusan,`

Some terms are clustered into multiple clusters,like term `data` is placed to Cluster 3 and Cluster 7.

Can you tell me how to us the `tfidfvectorizer` and `KMeans` properly? Your help is my happiness :)

Comment: Probably your vocanulary does contain repeated values on the step 2. You can stop degugger and try to clean up them.